# Array compare with for each performance issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays with array of objects as follows and one array will have more than 10k records and other have below 100 records

```
let bigArray = [{id:1, name:"Raj", level:0}, {id:2, name:"sushama", level:2}, {id:3, name:"Sushant", level:0}, {id:4, name:"Bhaskar", level:2},....upto 30k records] 

let smallArray = [{id:2, name:"sushama"}, {id:3, name:"Sushant"}....upto 100 records]
```

I want to find where in the index of bigArray in which the object from smallArray resides and add to another array say indexArray I tried below

```
let indexArray = []; 
bigArray.forEach((element, i) => {
  smallArray.forEach(ele => {
    if (element.name == ele.name && element.id == ele.id) {
      indexArray.push(i); return;
    } 
  }); 
});
```

But it takes time. What would be the fastest approach?

Comment: Please give an example output, it is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can there be multiple entries with the same `id` and `name` in `bigArray`?

Comment: No it won't have

Answer (score 4):

You can turn your `O(N^2)` approach into an `O(N)` approach by reducing the `bigArray` into an object indexed by a key made up from the `name` and `id`. Join the `name` and `id` by a character that isn't contained in either, such as `_`:

```
const indexArray = [];
const bigArrayIndiciesByNameAndId = bigArray.reduce((a, { name, id }, i) => {
  a[name + '_' + id] = i;
  return a;
}, {});

smallArray.forEach(ele => {
  const keyToFind = ele.name + '_' + ele.id;
  const foundIndex = bigArrayIndiciesByNameAndId[keyToFind];
  if (foundIndex) {
    indexArray.push(foundIndex);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool buddy I will try it

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `Map` and map the found indices.

```js
const getKey = ({ id, name }) => [id, name].join('|');

let bigArray = [{ id: 1, name: "Raj", level: 0 }, { id: 2, name: "sushama", level: 2 }, { id: 3, name: "Sushant", level: 0 }, { id: 4, name: "Bhaskar", level: 2 }],
    smallArray = [{ id: 2, name: "sushama" }, { id: 3, name: "Sushant" }],
    map = new Map(bigArray.map((o, i) => [getKey(o), i]))
    indexArray = smallArray.map((o) => map.get(getKey(o)));

console.log(indexArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

`return` will not "break" the `forEach` loop. A `forEach` can't be stopped. The `forEach` callback function will be called one time per items always. When you find the element, continue running the `forEach` loop is a waste of resouces.

You should use `for` instead:

```
let indexArray = []; 
bigArray.forEach((element, i) => {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < smallArray.length; ii++) {
        var ele = smallArray[ii];
        if (element.name == ele.name && element.id == ele.id) {
            indexArray.push(i);
            break; // This will break the "for" loop as we found the item
        }
    }
});
```

TIP: Always have a good indentation in your code. Actually your code is really bad indented to identify code blocks at first sight. I fixed it in this example.

Comment: Jump target can not cross function error. That is why I tried return